# how to get count in sql server while using inner joins?

Tags: sql-server, count, row, inner-join

I have following query:

```
SELECT  
   h.helpcontent, s.MenuID, s.pkSitePageId, s.PageAliasName,
   s.SitePageName,s.pagepath
FROM 
   tblSiteRolePermissions p
INNER JOIN 
   tblSitePages s ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
INNER JOIN 
   tblHelp h ON s.pkSitePageId=h.fkSitePageId
WHERE 
   (p.fkRoleId = 4 AND p.ViewOnly = 1) 
ORDER BY 
   s.pkSitePageId
```

I want to get count from `tblSiteRolePermissions`. I have tried the `Count` but its throwing some error like:

> *Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Column 'tblHelp.HelpContent' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in  either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Please help me and let me know where I am wrong.

**Update**

Here is the code I am trying:

```
SELECT 
    count(p.pkRolePermissionId), 
    h.helpcontent, s.MenuID, s.pkSitePageId, s.PageAliasName, 
    s.SitePageName, s.pagepath
FROM
    tblSiteRolePermissions p
INNER JOIN 
    tblSitePages s ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
INNER JOIN
    tblHelp h ON s.pkSitePageId = h.fkSitePageId
WHERE 
    (p.fkRoleId = 4 AND p.ViewOnly = 1) 
ORDER BY 
    s.pkSitePageId
```

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor please review my question i have updated it..

Comment: The error message does not match your sample SQL statement. There is neither a `count()` (or any other aggregate function) nor a `group by` in your statement. Please show us the real statement that produces the error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please review now

Comment: Do you want to get the count for **all** rows, or the count for just a single fkSitePageId? Or for some other combination of attributes?

Comment: no i want to get all row's count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a aggregate function, then you need to use a `GROUP BY` clause on the remaining fields in your `SELECT` statement that are not in an aggregate.  Similar to this:

```
SELECT  count(p.pkRolePermissionId) CountRolePermission,
  h.helpcontent, 
  s.MenuID, 
  s.pkSitePageId, 
  s.PageAliasName,
  s.SitePageName,
  s.pagepath
from tblSiteRolePermissions p
INNER JOIN tblSitePages s 
  ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
inner join tblHelp h 
  on s.pkSitePageId=h.fkSitePageId
WHERE (p.fkRoleId =4 and p.ViewOnly=1) 
GROUP BY h.helpcontent, 
  s.MenuID, 
  s.pkSitePageId, 
  s.PageAliasName,
  s.SitePageName,
  s.pagepath
ORDER BY s.pkSitePageId
```

If you want the count of all rows, then you can use something like this:

```
SELECT  NumRows.TotalCount,
  h.helpcontent, 
  s.MenuID, 
  s.pkSitePageId, 
  s.PageAliasName,
  s.SitePageName,
  s.pagepath
from tblSiteRolePermissions p
INNER JOIN tblSitePages s 
  ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
inner join tblHelp h 
  on s.pkSitePageId=h.fkSitePageId
cross join
(
  SELECT  count(*) TotalCount
  from tblSiteRolePermissions p
  INNER JOIN tblSitePages s 
    ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
  inner join tblHelp h 
    on s.pkSitePageId=h.fkSitePageId
  WHERE (p.fkRoleId =4 and p.ViewOnly=1) 
) NumRows
WHERE (p.fkRoleId =4 and p.ViewOnly=1) 
ORDER BY s.pkSitePageId
```

Or you can use CTE with your query, similar to this:

```
;with cte as 
(
  SELECT h.helpcontent, 
    s.MenuID, 
    s.pkSitePageId, 
    s.PageAliasName,
    s.SitePageName,
    s.pagepath
  from tblSiteRolePermissions p
  INNER JOIN tblSitePages s 
    ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
  inner join tblHelp h 
    on s.pkSitePageId=h.fkSitePageId
  WHERE (p.fkRoleId =4 and p.ViewOnly=1) 
)
select h.helpcontent, 
    s.MenuID, 
    s.pkSitePageId, 
    s.PageAliasName,
    s.SitePageName,
    s.pagepath, 
    (select count(*) from cte) as Total
from cte
```

Comment: @Visions that means that the data that you are counting is distinct because of the `GROUP BY`. What exactly are you attempting to `count()` that is important in determining the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(p.pkRolePermissionId),h.helpcontent, s.MenuID, s.pkSitePageId, s.PageAliasName,
s.SitePageName,s.pagepath
from tblSiteRolePermissions p
INNER JOIN tblSitePages s ON p.fkSitePageId = s.pkSitePageId
inner join tblHelp h on s.pkSitePageId=h.fkSitePageId
WHERE (p.fkRoleId =4 and p.ViewOnly=1) 
GROUP BY h.helpcontent, s.MenuID, s.pkSitePageId, s.PageAliasName,
s.SitePageName,s.pagepath
ORDER BY s.pkSitePageId
```